# AS3 - Add scroll bar to dynamically generated text field?

Tags: actionscript-3, flash

I'm new to actionscript 3, so please forgive me.

I am loading a text file into my flash file and then dynamically creating a text field which will take in the `myBody` text from that file.  The problem is that the text in `myBody` could be very long, so I would like to add a scroll bar when needed to the dynamically generated text field.  Is there any way to this?

```
var myTextLoader:URLLoader = new URLLoader();
myTextLoader.dataFormat=URLLoaderDataFormat.VARIABLES;

var myTextField_txt:TextField = new TextField();
myTextField_txt.multiline = true;
myTextField_txt.wordWrap = true;
myTextField_txt.border = true;
myTextField_txt.height = 100;

myTextLoader.addEventListener(Event.COMPLETE, onLoaded);

function onLoaded(e:Event):void {
     myTextField_txt.text = e.target.data.myBody;

     addChild(myTextField_txt);

}

myTextLoader.load(new URLRequest("mySampleFile.txt"));
```

Comment: If using flash Pro, you could instead use a `TextArea` component, which wraps a text field in a scroll pane basically. At any rate, there isn't one built in for the base `TextField` class.  You either need to use a pre-made component (like `TextArea` or `UIScrollBar` from the `fl.controls` package), or roll your own.